# Automapping a List<SomeObject> to a class that has a property of List<SomeObject>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Ok I have a view named SearchResults that displays results from a user search. So I have a view model named SearchResultsView. SearchResultsView has a property List that it gets from a service. So I want to use automapper to populate the SearchResultsView class with the List. I could change the service to return a SearchResults class that also has a property with a List but in this case I would rather just config AutoMapper to take the List it got from the service as source and map it into the SearchResultsView property.

```
public class SearchResultsView
{
    public List<SearchResult> Results { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public List<string> URIs { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<List<SearchResult>, SearchResultsView>();
```

Comment: explain better your problem, maybe with small rilevant pieces of code

Comment: ok did a complete edit on it hope that helps. I could easily do SearchResultsView.Results = "response from server" just wanted to setup using fluent mapping if possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's one quick way you could do this, using `.ConstructUsing`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<SearchResult>, SearchResultsView>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new SearchResultsView { Results = src });
```

However, if this is all you're doing with AutoMapper, I would probably just assign `Results` directly as you mention in your comment.

Comment: No most other views have a more standard mapping just wanted to stick with convention and use automapper for them all if possible